# What is an example of contravariant use in Rust?

Tags: rust, contravariance

In the [Nomicon's section about subtyping](https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.33.0/nomicon/subtyping.html), it says contravariance is available for a function pointer type.  However, I can't find any good examples of this.  I tried to code a struct with a function pointer, but the contravariance doesn't seem to work.

What is a code example of this?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

[Rust's notion of subtyping **only applies to lifetimes**.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55200843/155423)

---

Searching for the term "contra" on [the page you linked](https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.33.0/nomicon/subtyping.html) has numerous relevant paragraphs:

> Actually witnessing contravariance is quite difficult in Rust, though it does in fact exist.

> NOTE: the only source of contravariance in the language is the arguments to a function, which is why it really doesn't come up much in practice. Invoking contravariance involves higher-order programming with function pointers that take references with specific lifetimes (as opposed to the usual "any lifetime", which gets into higher rank lifetimes, which work independently of subtyping).

> And that's why function types, unlike anything else in the language, are contravariant over their arguments.

The page ends with an example of all the types of contravariance. Applying it...

#### Contravariance

```
struct MyContraType<Mixed> {
    k1: fn(Mixed), // contravariant over Mixed
}

fn contra_example<'short>(
    mut a: MyContraType<&'short u8>,
    mut b: MyContraType<&'static u8>,
    x: fn(&'short u8),
    y: fn(&'static u8),
) {
    a.k1 = x;
    a.k1 = y; // Fails
    b.k1 = x;
    b.k1 = y;
}
```

The contravariant example does not allow substituting `'static` for `'short`:

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> src/lib.rs:12:12
   |
12 |     a.k1 = y;
   |            ^ lifetime mismatch
   |
   = note: expected type `fn(&'short u8)`
              found type `fn(&'static u8)`
note: the lifetime 'short as defined on the function body at 5:19...
  --> src/lib.rs:5:19
   |
5  | fn contra_example<'short>(
   |                   ^^^^^^
   = note: ...does not necessarily outlive the static lifetime
```

#### Covariance

```
struct MyCoType<Mixed> {
    k1: fn() -> Mixed, // covariant over Mixed
}

fn co_example<'short>(
    mut a: MyCoType<&'short u8>,
    mut b: MyCoType<&'static u8>,
    x: fn() -> &'short u8,
    y: fn() -> &'static u8,
) {
    a.k1 = x;
    a.k1 = y;
    b.k1 = x; // Fails
    b.k1 = y;
}
```

The covariant example does not allow substituting `'short` for `'static`:

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> src/lib.rs:29:12
   |
29 |     b.k1 = x;
   |            ^ lifetime mismatch
   |
   = note: expected type `fn() -> &'static u8`
              found type `fn() -> &'short u8`
note: the lifetime 'short as defined on the function body at 21:15...
  --> src/lib.rs:21:15
   |
21 | fn co_example<'short>(
   |               ^^^^^^
   = note: ...does not necessarily outlive the static lifetime
```