# Why does SmallVec have different behaviour when storing types with lifetimes compared to Vec?

Tags: rust, lifetime

I've got three examples, one using `Vec` one using `SmallVec`, and one with my own implementation of `SmallVec`. The ones using `Vec` and my own `SmallVec` compile but the one using the real `SmallVec` does not.

#### Working example using `Vec`

```rust
use std::borrow::Cow;
use std::collections::HashMap;

pub trait MyTrait {
    fn get_by_id(&self, id: usize) -> &ItemTraitReturns;
}

/// IMPORTANT PART IS HERE: `Vec<Cow<'a, str>>`
pub struct ItemTraitReturns<'a>(Vec<Cow<'a, str>>);

/// this implementation only takes items with static lifetime (but other implementations also might have different lifetimes)
pub struct MyTraitStruct {
    map: HashMap<usize, ItemTraitReturns<'static>>,
}

impl MyTrait for MyTraitStruct {
    fn get_by_id(&self, id: usize) -> &ItemTraitReturns {
        let temp: &ItemTraitReturns<'static> = self.map.get(&id).unwrap();
        // Works as expected: I expect that I can return `&ItemTraitReturns<'_>`
        // when I have `&ItemTraitReturns<'static>` (since 'static outlives everything).
        temp
        // Will return `&ItemTraitReturns<'_>`
    }
}
```

#### Failing example with SmallVec

Uses `SmallVec` instead of `Vec` with no other changes.

```rust
use smallvec::SmallVec;
use std::borrow::Cow;
use std::collections::HashMap;

pub trait MyTrait {
    fn get_by_id(&self, id: usize) -> &ItemTraitReturns;
}

/// IMPORTANT PART IS HERE: Uses SmallVec instead of Vec
pub struct ItemTraitReturns<'a>(SmallVec<[Cow<'a, str>; 2]>);

/// this implementation only takes items with static lifetime (but other implementations also might have different lifetimes)
pub struct MyTraitStruct {
    map: HashMap<usize, ItemTraitReturns<'static>>,
}

impl MyTrait for MyTraitStruct {
    fn get_by_id(&self, id: usize) -> &ItemTraitReturns {
        let temp: &ItemTraitReturns<'static> = self.map.get(&id).unwrap();
        temp
    }
}
```

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> src/lib.rs:23:9
   |
23 |         temp
   |         ^^^^ lifetime mismatch
   |
   = note: expected type `&ItemTraitReturns<'_>`
              found type `&ItemTraitReturns<'static>`
note: the anonymous lifetime #1 defined on the method body at 18:5...
  --> src/lib.rs:18:5
   |
18 | /     fn get_by_id(&self, id: usize) -> &ItemTraitReturns {
19 | |         let temp: &ItemTraitReturns<'static> = self.map.get(&id).unwrap();
20 | |         // Error:
21 | |         //    = note: expected type `&demo2::ItemTraitReturns<'_>`
22 | |         //              found type `&demo2::ItemTraitReturns<'static>`
23 | |         temp
24 | |     }
   | |_____^
   = note: ...does not necessarily outlive the static lifetime
```

#### Working example with my own `SmallVec`

When I implement my own (very naive) `SmallVec<[T; 2]>` (called `NaiveSmallVec2<T>`) the code also compiles... Very strange!

```rust
use std::borrow::Cow;
use std::collections::HashMap;

/// This is a very naive implementation of a SmallVec<[T; 2]>
pub struct NaiveSmallVec2<T> {
    item1: Option<T>,
    item2: Option<T>,
    more: Vec<T>,
}

impl<T> NaiveSmallVec2<T> {
    pub fn push(&mut self, item: T) {
        if self.item1.is_none() {
            self.item1 = Some(item);
        } else if self.item2.is_none() {
            self.item2 = Some(item);
        } else {
            self.more.push(item);
        }
    }

    pub fn element_by_index(&self, index: usize) -> Option<&T> {
        match index {
            0 => self.item1.as_ref(),
            1 => self.item2.as_ref(),
            _ => self.more.get(index - 2),
        }
    }
}

pub trait MyTrait {
    fn get_by_id(&self, id: usize) -> &ItemTraitReturns;
}

/// IMPORTANT PART IS HERE: Uses NaiveSmallVec2
pub struct ItemTraitReturns<'a>(NaiveSmallVec2<Cow<'a, str>>);

/// only takes items with static lifetime
pub struct MyTraitStruct {
    map: HashMap<usize, ItemTraitReturns<'static>>,
}

impl MyTrait for MyTraitStruct {
    fn get_by_id(&self, id: usize) -> &ItemTraitReturns {
        let temp: &ItemTraitReturns<'static> = self.map.get(&id).unwrap();
        // astonishingly this works!
        temp
    }
}
```

---

I expect the `SmallVec` version to compile like the `Vec` version does. I don't understand why in some cases (in the case of `Vec`) `&ItemTraitReturns<'static>` can be converted to `&ItemTraitReturns<'_>` and in some cases (`SmallVec`) it's not possible (I don't see the influence of `Vec` / `SmallVec`).

I don't want to change lifetimes of this trait:

```rust
pub trait MyTrait {
    fn get_by_id(&self, id: usize) -> &ItemTraitReturns;
}
```

... since when using the trait I don't care about lifetimes (this should be an implementation detail) ... but still would like to use `SmallVec`.

Comment: It looks like your question might be answered by the answers of [How do I add references to a container when the borrowed values are created after the container?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44987645/155423); specifically the part about `may_dangle`. If not, please **[edit]** your question to explain the differences. Otherwise, we can mark this question as already answered.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This difference appears to be caused by a difference in *variance* between `Vec` and `SmallVec`.  While `Vec<T>` is *covariant* in `T`, `SmallVec` appears to be *invariant*. As a result, `SmallVec<[&'a T; 1]>` can't be converted to `SmallVec<[&'b T; 1]>` even when lifetime `'a` outlives `'b` and the conversion should be safe. Here is a minimal example triggering the compiler error:

```
fn foo<'a, T>(x: SmallVec<[&'static T; 1]>) -> SmallVec<[&'a T; 1]> {
    x  // Compiler error here: lifetime mismatch
}

fn bar<'a, T>(x: Vec<&'static T>) -> Vec<&'a T> {
    x  // Compiles fine
}
```

This appears to be a shortcoming of `SmallVec`. Variance is automatically determined by the compiler, and it is sometimes cumbersome to convince the compiler that it is safe to assume that a type is covariant.

There is an [open Github issue for this problem](https://github.com/servo/rust-smallvec/issues/146).

Unfortunately, I don't know a way of figuring out the variance of a type based on its public interface. Variance is not included in the documentation, and depends on the private implementation details of a type. You can read more on variance [in the language reference](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/subtyping.html) or [in the Nomicon](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nomicon/subtyping.html).

Comment: Additional questions have also been asked about lifetime variance: [Covariance of Box type in Rust](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55200843/155423); [What is an example of contravariant use in Rust?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55344893/155423)

Comment: Thank you very much! That's exactly what I was looking for:

 * https://github.com/bluss/arrayvec/issues/96
 * https://doc.rust-lang.org/nomicon/subtyping.html#variance

Unfortunately it seems that I have to get rid of SmallVec in my project (until it's covariant like Vec): The type `ItemTraitReturns` in my project is a lot more complex and this invariance inherits tru the entire hierarchy.